# Notification led without triggering a system notification

Tags: android, notifications

I would like to use the RBG notification LED (where available) as a *signal*, for example imagine I want to flash red very quickly 3 times the LED when you are using my app and battery gets bellow 5% (silly example but you get the picture).

I know how to do this with a system notification but is there any way to do this without triggering it? You can programmatically launch it and then discard it but is there any way to **completely** avoid using `Notification`?

Comment: @Snicolas please carefully read my question, is there any way to completely avoid using Notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to completely avoid using Notification in this case would be to use Manufacturer SDK (if exists - and this is not likely), but even if... you need to treat every device separately because of different SDKs (I guess you don't want to do this).

Comment: it seems to be the only way ATM so I'll take a no for answer